# WAMP- PHP functions returns nothing or no access

Tags: php, function, wamp, global

I have a problem with my WAMP (I think), I cant get anything from any function in my applications, for example var_dump($_POST) works fine until I place it in a function then nothing comes, same thing with a simple echo, works fine alone but nothing in a function, even return values don't work. Any idea guys??

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST); //works fine

if(isset($_POST)) {
 function dump() {
  echo 'HELLO WORLD!'; //not working even if I call this function
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you call your function any where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
 dump();
}

function dump() {
  echo 'HELLO WORLD!'; //not working even if I call this function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST)) {
    dumpit();
    }

     function dumpit() {
      echo 'HELLO WORLD!'; //not working even if I call this function
     }
```

be sure you post something to the page otherwise the function dumpit() will not get called. If you do not post something you can test like so...

```
 <?php

    dumpit();

     function dumpit() {
      echo 'HELLO WORLD!'; //not working even if I call this function
     }
```

please go through some tutorials for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code on my localhost (I'm running XAMPP) and it executed normally.
I tried Code:

```
$a =10;
if(isset($a))
{
    function dump($str)
    {
        echo $str; //not working even if I call this function 
    }
    dump('Calling from within the if statement');
}

dump('Calling from outside the if statement');
```

Then, I called this dump(); function both from within the if() condition scope and outside the if condition scope. And it worked well in both situations.

I think the problem is with your $_POST variable. Try re-considering it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it seems that my WAMP hanged up, so I restarted windows and the WAMP just worked fine, now works, thanks for your time guys! happy to help any time ;-)